Issue with `bootstrap.servers` in Kafka Producer Configuration with Spring Boot 3.2.6 and Spring Cloud 2023.0.2
I am experiencing an issue with Kafka producer configuration in my Spring Boot application after upgrading to newer versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud dependencies.
Environment

Spring Boot: 3.2.6
Spring Cloud Dependencies: 2023.0.2
Spring Cloud Config Server

Problem Description
In Spring Boot 2.7.8 with Spring Cloud Dependencies 2021.0.8, the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration class that creates DefaultKafkaProducerFactory bean by method kafkaProducerFactory was correctly populated with properties from the Spring Config Server, including the bootstrap.servers property.
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ProducerFactory.class)
    public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> kafkaProducerFactory(
            ObjectProvider<DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer> customizers) {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                this.properties.buildProducerProperties());
        String transactionIdPrefix = this.properties.getProducer().getTransactionIdPrefix();
        if (transactionIdPrefix != null) {
            factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix);
        }
        customizers.orderedStream().forEach((customizer) -> customizer.customize(factory));
        return factory;
    }

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.6 and Spring Cloud Dependencies 2023.0.2, I noticed that the DefaultKafkaProducerFactory's bean created by method kafkaProducerFactory configuration logic has changed. Specifically, the addition of  this.applyKafkaConnectionDetailsForProducer(properties, connectionDetails); is now used, which overwrites the bootstrap.servers property set by the Spring Config server value to localhost:9092.
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ProducerFactory.class})
    public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaConnectionDetails connectionDetails, ObjectProvider<DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer> customizers, ObjectProvider<SslBundles> sslBundles) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = this.properties.buildProducerProperties((SslBundles)sslBundles.getIfAvailable());
        this.applyKafkaConnectionDetailsForProducer(properties, connectionDetails);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(properties);
        String transactionIdPrefix = this.properties.getProducer().getTransactionIdPrefix();
        if (transactionIdPrefix != null) {
            factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix);
        }

        customizers.orderedStream().forEach((customizer) -> {
            customizer.customize(factory);
        });
        return factory;
    }

The KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS environment variable is set correctly, and this configuration is supposed to be fetched from the Spring Config Server. I see the Map<String, Object> properties = this.properties.buildProducerProperties((SslBundles)sslBundles.getIfAvailable()); correctly populated the properties with bootstrap.servers -> my.eastus2.azure.confluent.cloud:9092. However the next step overwrites that with localhost:9092
Configuration Snippet
Here is a snippet of my configuration that works in the older versions but fails in the new versions:
# application.yml
spring:
  # To overwrite properties loaded from App Config, include below line in application.yml
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:https://my.config.server.com/v1/config/
   producer:
     key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
     value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    properties:
      ### Auth ###
      sasl.jaas.config: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required \
        clientId='${my_client_id}' \
        clientSecret='${my_client_secret}' \
        scope='' \
        extension_logicalCluster='${my_kafka_cluster_id}' \
        extension_identityPoolId='${my_identity_pool}';"

      ### Schema Registry ###
      bearer.auth.client.id: ${my_client_id}
      bearer.auth.client.secret: ${my_client_secret}
      bearer.auth.identity.pool.id: ${my_identity_pool:pool-xyz}

      kekcipherkms.provider.identity.client.id: ${my_client_id}
      kekcipherkms.provider.identity.client.secret: ${my_client_secret}
      kekcipherkms.provider.identity.scope: my.scope.w

    ### Producer ###
    producer:
      properties:
        topic: ${topic}

Observed Behavior

Spring Boot 2.7.8 + Spring Cloud 2021.0.8: The DefaultKafkaProducerFactory correctly uses the bootstrap.servers value from the Config Server.
Spring Boot 3.2.6 + Spring Cloud 2023.0.2: The bootstrap.servers value is overwritten to localhost:9092 by the applyKafkaConnectionDetailsForProducer method.

Expected Behavior
The DefaultKafkaProducerFactory should use the bootstrap.servers property from the Spring Config Server as it did in the previous versions.
Question
How can I configure my Spring Boot application to correctly use the bootstrap.servers value from the Spring Config Server in the newer versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud? Is there something I am missing to ensure KafkaConnectionDetails bootstrap.servers = my Spring Config Servers value and not the default localhost:9092 ?
Additional Context
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights on the changes introduced in the newer versions that might be affecting this behavior, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Found my answer with a little more searching on Stack overflow and a little help from these other posts that were similar:
why is springboot not picking up apache kafka bootstrap-servers in application.yml? answer by Gary Russell
Kafka client connection issue for spring boot 3.1.X and above answer by Artem Bilan
The existing Spring Config Server is providing a spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers value but since Spring Boot 3.1.0 it needs to be spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers
So my hack of a solution until I can submit a ticket to have the company update the spring config server was to do the following :
# application.yml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers}

